# How to install or integrate bundles in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

i have downloaded a sonata admin bundle, and have placed in `/var/www/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle`, and have made an entry in `AppKernel.php` as  `$bundles = array( ...  new Symfony\Bundle\SonataAdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),)`, but throwing an error as

> Fatal error: Class
>   'Symfony\Bundle\SonataAdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle' not found in
>   /var/www/Symfony/app/AppKernel.php on line 21 Call Stack: 0.0001
>   326332 1. {main}() /var/www/Symfony/web/app_dev.php:0 0.0122 1121592
>   2. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle()

please help me as i am very new to symfony 2. As a whole please give a link or detail like how to install/configure any bundle that is downloaded.
Thanks
Ravi.M

Comment: In which namespace is the SonataAdminBundle class?

Comment: You usually have to register a new namespace in `app/autoload.php`. Are you sure you did that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to move the bundle to

```
/var/www/Symfony/vendor/bundles
```

Then in AppKernel.php add

```
new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
```

in your $bundles array.

In autoload.php add

```
'Sonata'           => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
```

to the `$loader->registerNamespaces` array

Answer (score 5):

First off, `SonataAdminBundle` lives in `Sonata` namespace, not `Symfony`. So you'll have to rewrite the instantiation in `app/AppKernel.php` to:

```
new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle()
```

You also have to register namespace in `app/autoload.php`:

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
...
'Sonata' => __DIR__.'/path/to/parent/of/Sonata/folder'
...
));
```