# Symfony2 - Fatal error with Bundles

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I've got the error [Solution at the end of the question]

```
Fatal error: Class 'symblog\Blogger\BlogBundle\SymblogBundle' not found in
/var/www/Symfony/app/AppKernel.php on line 20
```

I founded the question [How to install or integrate bundles in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585383/how-to-install-or-integrate-bundles-in-symfony2), but the solutions given didn't help me, because I already did what is suggested there. I'm following the tutorial [symblog.co.uk](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/configuration-and-templating.html) except that I created at

```
app/config/routing.yml
```

a

```
*.php resource
```

Thanks in advance!

I have to add that while registering the bundle by console I've got the error

```
The command was not able to configure everything automatically.
You must do the following changes manually.
```

And the instructions:

```
- Edit the app/autoload.php file and register the bundle
namespace at the top of the registerNamespaces() call:
'symblog\Blogger\BlogBundle' => '/var/www/Symfony/blog',
```

which I followed.

AppKernel.php

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        //..
        new symblog\Blogger\BlogBundle\SymblogBundle(),
    );
```

/app/config/routing.yml

```
SymblogBundle:
resource: "@SymblogBundle/Resources/config/routing.php"
prefix:   /
```

As requested: /app/config/config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.ini }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    charset:         UTF-8
    router:          { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml" }
    form:            true
    csrf_protection: true
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:      { engines: ['twig'] } #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    session:
        default_locale: %locale%
        auto_start:     true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    # java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        # closure:
        #     jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/compiler.jar
        # yui_css:
        #     jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%

jms_security_extra:
    secure_controllers:  true
    secure_all_services: false
```

[Edit] The solution was very easy after the answer from @Clamidity that the bundles usually are located at src/Blogger/SymBlogBundle/BloggerSymBlogBundle.php

While the configuration using the console it saked about the location of the bundle and the default was /../src but I changed to /../blog. And of course it won't work, Symfony was looking into the wrong location. What I did was to move the folders inside /blog to /src and everything went fine.

Comment: Did you get your class name right? Are you sure it's "symblog\Blogger\BlogBundle\SymblogBundle" and not "Symblog\Blogger\BlogBundle\SymblogBundle" (notice uppercase "S")?

Comment: What is the file path to your bundle?

Comment: The file path is /var/www/Symfony/blog

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few things that it could be. I'll just cover anything I can think of.

1. Generally bundles are placed in the src folder. So the path to your bundle should look like this.

   ```
   src/Blogger/SymBlogBundle/BloggerSymBlogBundle.php
   ```

   (Notice that the bundle name follows the file name convention)
2. Inside of the BloggerSymBlogBundle.php make sure you have something similar to the following:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Blogger\SymBlogBundle;

   use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

   class BloggerSymBlogBundle extends Bundle
   { 
   }
   ```

   (Notice that the same name convention is also followed here)
3. In your autoload.php the namespace that should be registered is the "Blogger" part of the name/path to your bundle. This is because the bundle itself resides in the Blogger folder:

   ```
   'Blogger' => __DIR__.'/../src',
   ```

   (Notice that the folder listed is the parent of the Blogger folder)
4. Now in the AppKernel.php register the bundle according the namespace your set up and registered:

   ```
   new Blogger\SymBlogBundle\BloggerSymBlogBundle(),
   ```

   *Note - Your resources and references to this bundle with the above configuration would be

   ```
   BloggerSymBlogBundle
   ```

   so your php routing would be called by using:

   ```
   @BloggerSymBlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.php
   ```

Answer (score 4):

There are different solution.

Clear the app/cache/(prod|dev) folder. When you have edited the Appkernel and autoload.

> Fatal error: Class 'symblog\Blogger\BlogBundle\SymblogBundle' not found in
>       /var/www/Symfony/app/AppKernel.php on line 20

Here are now different Problems:

1. Look to the SymblogBundle.php in the Bundle Folder and look which namespace they use. Perhaps its really an uppercase ("S") like @kuba said.
2. The Class file is not in the folder or you have no rights to the folder that the interpreter can load the file.
3. I think your autoload.php is not correct.

   ```
   'Avalanche'        => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
   ```

   This is the common way to register an Namespace. In your case it have to be

   ```
   'Symlog' => '/var/www/Symfony/blog',
   ```

[Here are the instructions from the "BloggerBundle"](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/configuration-and-templating.html) I hope its the correct one

There you can see the your autoload its not correct the Namespace is "Blogger".