# symfony2: class included in AppKernel can not be found

Tags: symfony

I have this `app/AppKernel`:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
            new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\JMSI18nRoutingBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Sports\FrontendBundle\SportsFrontendBundle(),   // line 25             
            new Sports\UserBundle\SportsUserBundle(),
            new Sonata\DefaultBundle\SonataDefaultBundle(),
            new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
            new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
            new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
            new Sonata\CacheBundle\SonataCacheBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
            new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle()
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
#$bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
```

And this class `src/Sports/FrontendBundle/SportsFrontendBundle.php`:

```
namespace Sports\FrontendBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class SportsFrontendBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

And Im getting this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Sports\FrontendBundle\SportsFrontendBundle' not
>   found in /home/tirengarfio/programacion/sports/app/AppKernel.php on
>   line 25

This is my `app/autoload.php`:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

if (!$loader = @include __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php') {

    $message = <<< EOF
<p>You must set up the project dependencies by running the following commands:</p>
<pre>
    curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
    php composer.phar install
</pre>

EOF;

    if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
        $message = strip_tags($message);
    }

    die($message);
}

// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';

    $loader->add('', __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs');
    $loader->add('Sports',   __DIR__ . '/../src');
}

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

and my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.1",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.2.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "dev-master",
        "twig/extensions": "dev-master",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "*",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "jms/i18n-routing-bundle" : "1.0.*",
        "sonata-project/exporter" : "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/jquery-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/block-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/cache-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web"
    }
}
```

Any idea?

sf 2.1.1

Javi

Comment: Paste whole listing of `AppKernel`, please. And check if you added your namespace to `autoload.php`

Comment: You could also paste your `composer.json` file.

Comment: The files look OK. Have you checked your directory structure? Maybe there is a typo in the name of one of the directories or of the file

Comment: @AdrienBrault I added my `composer.json`

Comment: @CarlosGranados I checked the directory structure, anyway I edited my question with the name of paths.

Comment: Check this answer -->http://stackoverflow.com/a/9898907/2142093 It has a very good answer. It worked well for me

Answer (score 7):

For future references, similar issues can happen if you checkout your code and copy the vendor folder directly without running composer.

To rule autoload issues out, you can simply run `install` in your symfony2 folder ( assuming you have `composer.phar` there ):

```
php composer.phar install
```

This will install the project dependencies from the composer.lock file if present, or fall back on the composer.json.

Answer (score 5):

It just was a permissions issue. My bundle folder somehow got wrong permissions. I set them to 755 and it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 4):

In your autoload.php you need something like:

```
$loader->add('Sports',   __DIR__ . '/../src');
```

Unless you have Sports coming in under vendor?

===========================================

So just to confirm you have:

sports

sports/app

sports/app/console

sports/src

sports/src/Sports/FrontendBundle/SportsFrontendBundle.php

sports/vendor

Windows or unix?  And you get the error when you run the console command?

Comment: `src` folder is already added in the loader by default as he is using composer. Also if it was namespace problem the error would have occurred in `new Sports\UserBundle\SportsUserBundle(),` line. I am guessing there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: Yep.  I saw that that as well.  Bit puzzling.

Comment: @m2mdas I couldn't find any typo.. Anyway I added the `$loader` line in autoload. I edited my question with the name of the folders. Besides, placing my cursor over `SportsFrontendBundle()` I can go to the class source.