# Symfony2 - Composer messed up my site as all bundles don't exist

Tags: symfony, composer-php

Everything was great with my Symfony2 setup until I started messing around with Composer.

I did install Symfony2 with Composer, but then manually added bundles - including ones I created myself.

Then, I needed to add something which seemed easier with Composer. Lots of messing around in the Terminal later I then find when I run in a browser I get an error in AppKernel.php saying none of the bundles exist - including:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle' not found in /path/app/AppKernel.php line 39
```

I'm 100% the folders exist and nothing has changed other than running various Composer commands.

Composer has no reference to these bundles.

How do I resolve this? I'm guessing I either tell Composer to clear off (like before) or somehow I get Composer to understand the bundles.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the bootstrap file. I believe Composer will create one after being updated, but this is where I'm struggling.

--

composer.json:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"extra": {
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us the content of your `composer.json` ? Also, is this bundle in `/path/to/application/src/Acme/DemoBundle/` ?

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I've added the composer.json. The bundles are all in the /path/to/application/src/ folder, and they have always worked before which is the strange thing.

Comment: Autoloading seems to be correct since you have a fallback on `src` folder. Maybe it is a [permission issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12536923/1607098) ?

Comment: Thanks. So is it not anything to do with the bootstrap file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't update `app/autoload.php` file. Check the source of standard distribution: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/autoload.php

You need to include `vendor/autoload.php`, which is generated by the composer.