# How to add a Bundle?

Tags: symfony, bundle

I want add this [bundle](https://github.com/robzienert/CalendarBundle) but I don't know how install it in my project.

I use Ubuntu, my project is located in var/www/Symfony. Any clue ?

Comment: Should really help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585383/how-to-install-or-integrate-bundles-in-symfony2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find his bundle on packagist.org under: https://packagist.org/packages/ricktg/calendar-bundle

Just insert

```
"ricktg/calendar-bundle": "dev-master"
```

into your composer.json in your web folder and run a

```
composer.phar update
```

In your console.

Comment: I made a search on Packagist but *CalendarBundle* return no results.. By the way, it could be interesting to describe an installation **without** composer. Even if I know that's the best way to do.

Comment: @j0k Guess it _could_ be interesting, but I think thats nothing to start with.

Comment: @KingCrunch of course. It was just a case where a Bundle isn't available on packagist

Comment: @j0k Makes sense, but I would recommend to use composer anyway, but (in this case of course) without packagist: You can define custom repository-locations in `composer.json`, or you can even setup an own package-like service via `satis` (useful for a companies closed-source bundles). Just want to say, that I would stick with one system once I've adopted it :)