# Symfony2 Composer Bundle Namespace

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-2.3, autoloader

I'm trying for a while to import an own bundle via composer but I got a few problems. I got following bundle:

```
<?php

namespace Platform\Bundle\PollBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class PlatformPollBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

The bundle is in *vendor/platform/pollbundle/*.

In the "main" *composer.json* I definied the namespace for autoloading:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/" ,
        "Platform\\": "vendor/platform"
    }
},
```

and in the *composer.json* from the bundle I definied:

```
{
    "name" : "platform/pollbundle",
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "extra": {
        "servicePath": ""
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Platform\\Bundle\\PollBundle": ""
        }
    },
    "target-dir": "pollbundle"
```

}

In the autoload_namespaces there is correctly following line:

```
'Platform\\' => array($vendorDir . '/platform'),
```

But I got the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Platform\Bundle\PollBundle\PlatformPollBundle' not found in     ........Controller.php on line 13
```

I tried about 100 solutions but nothing works. Would be great if somebody can help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install or integrate bundles in Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585383/how-to-install-or-integrate-bundles-in-symfony2) <-- it's not composer that manages symfony2 bundles, that's symfony. Check the duplicate question

Comment: First thanks for your answer but that dont work for me. I moved the bundle to /vendor/bundles and add it to the composer(same namespace??) in die autoload i tried the "$loader->registerNamespaces" but that method is not defined

Comment: forget about composer. The autoloading of the bundles is handled by AppKernel.php, in the `registerBundles` method. It's a hacky fix, but perhaps try running `php app/console generate:bundle` on the command-line, generate a new bundle with the same name as the one you're trying to add (`PollBundle`), then overwrite that dir (`src/PollBundle`) with the one you're trying to add, see if that works

Comment: Oh, and `$loader->registerNamespaces` is indeed wrong, it should be `AnnotationRegistry::registerAutoloadNamespace('PollBundle', 'path/to/PollBundle');`, that should be added to the `app/autoload.php` file

Comment: your second comment works!!! thank you very very much!

Comment: Mind if I post it as an answer, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundles aren't loaded by composer, but instead are handled by the Symfony kernel itself. In the app directory, edit AppKernel.php like this:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        ...,
        new Platform\Bundle\PollBundle\PlatformPollBundle()//<-- add this
    );
}
```

In the app/autoload.php file, meanwhile, register the new namesepace. It used to be done through the `$loader` instance, by calling `$loader->registerNameSpaces()`, but now, you have to call a static method on the `AnnotationRegistry` class:

```
AnnotationRegistry::registerAutoloadNamespace('PollBundle', 'path/to/PollBundle');
```

A hacky fix I suggested, which is apparently what fixed it for you, would be to run `php app/console generate:bundle` in the console, to generate a new bundle with the same name, and then simply replace that bundle's directory (in src/) with your bundle.

Comment: I dont try this ^^ i mean your second comment "forget about composer. The autoloading of the bundles is handled by AppKernel.php, in the registerBundles method. It's a hacky fix, but perhaps try running php app/console generate:bundle on the command-line, generate a new bundle with the same name as the one you're trying to add (PollBundle), then overwrite that dir (src/PollBundle) with the one you're trying to add, see if that works"

Comment: @Bee: added that to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong to define ANY autoloading in the main application for anything pointing into the vendor folder! That's what composer is for. Composer will read the autoload declaration for every package contained in there and add the appropriate autoloading automatically. There is no need to add this yourself.

And even if you have to use software that didn't yet add a composer.json file, the autoloading of only that package should go into the package definition block, not into the autoload definition.

Comment: And that is what he dont do. I got am compose.json in my package and the composer dont read it.

Comment: When you define `"psr-0": {"Platform\\Bundle\\PollBundle": ""}`, and you try to load a class `Platform\Bundle\PollBundle\PlatformPollBundle`, this class has to be in the path `Platform/Bundle/PollBundle/PlatformPollBundle.php` of your bundle. You didn't mention the filename in your question - can you verify the path is correct? Note that your definition in the main composer.json does not change anything about this, so if the bundle itself didn't work, your additional autoloading didn't fix anything. In fact it makes things worse (it is also affecting autoload performance).

Comment: the problem i got is that the composer.json from the bundle/package wont be loaded by the composer. For example i need the "extra" fields and i defined it in the package composer.json but i cant use it.